# SQL JDBC interceptor for Java that can trace suspicious SQL queries

Tags: java, sql, performance, hibernate, jdbc

I am running a Java program with Hibernate. Hibernate generates queries, but we also have some custom DAO queries. Static code analysis/reviews for poorly designed SQL queries is quite hard  and resource intensive to do, but they cause real trouble. Is there some JDBC interceptor available, that can warn about sub-par or poorly written SQL queries? I know there are sql monitors such has log4-jdbc, but to my knowledge they do not trace this kind of information at runtime.

By heuristic I mean, that executing a 5s lasting query once a day is ok, but executing 100 of these 5s lasting queries every minute is not ok. Or it could warn about sql queries not containing WHERE statement, which pulls out a large number of rows every time.

Comment: Perhaps you should log them as you say and use log forensics tools like Sumo Logic, to determine which are the problematic ones later on.

Comment: mysql provide a slow query log that can help, but the analysis is manual

Comment: SHouldn't this job be done by the database itself. It receives all the queries, executes them, knows what time and what execution plan they use. I'm not a DBA, but I've worked with DBAs doing those kinds of analyses with Oracle.

Comment: yes this is possible to do in DB2. But it would be interesting to receive this information by a jdbc interceptor, since developers usually check the server logs, not DB. This would provide fast feedback

Comment: Good profiling tool like JProfiler can trace such kind of JDBC queries.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like [XRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/xrebel/) could solve the issue? You could set thresholds to get notifications if the query is running too long or if too many queries were executed. Plus, you could actually spot N+1 issues just by looking at the results. And the queries are logged with inlined parameters, so you wouldn't have to figure out which parameter is which.